# Is everything ok with this notation? $A=\{x\mid 2x,x\in\Bbb{N}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I couldn't understand this notation. Is everything ok with this notation?

[image]

I would write it like this:

$$A=\left\{n: n=2k, k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\right\}$$

or

$$A=\left\{n\mid n=2k, k\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\right\}$$

or

$$A=\left\{n: \text{n is an even natural number}\right\}$$

or

$$A=\left\{n\mid \text{n is an even natural number}\right\}$$

Comment: I agree that that notation is very unclear. It looks to me like it should mean $\{x \, |\, 2x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } x \in \mathbb{N}\}$ which would just be $\mathbb{N}$ since every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfies $2x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It could also just be a typo. I would ask whoever wrote this.

Comment: @jairtaylor $x=1/2$ satisfies $2x\in\mathbb N$ so that would not be $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose but $x=1/2$ does not satisfy $x \in \mathbb{N}$. in my interpretation both $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $2x \in \mathbb{N}$ must be satisfied. I don't know if that's what the author intended; it is unclear.

Comment: What is the context of this notation? Is $A$ actually *used* later; if so, how? Is this option "III" of a multiple-choice list of ways of denoting the described set $A$, such that the author's intention is that this option should be discarded as nonsense? A screenshot of the full exercise or page might help clear this up.

Comment: @JairTaylor  It's almost certainly *not* what the book intended (if it was, they would have just used $\mathbb N$.  But if we apply set notation properly that *is* the only way to interpret it.   ... I figure the author either meant $\{x|2x\in \mathbb N$ OR $x\in \mathbb N\} = \{\frac 12, 1, 1\frac 12, 2, .....\}$ (although then the OR $x\in \mathbb N$ is redundant).  Or maybe the book meant $\{2x| x\in \mathbb N\} = \{2,4,6,8,....\}$.  But as written it is .... simply $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Please attach more images of the pages in and around the book. Even better, if the book is online, provide a link. As written, one can only guess the intentions of the author (which is exactly what has happened below). Whether this is a typo or not, may become more clear following the viewing of those images. It may even happen that the set is just $\mathbb N$ and this was a exercise meant to stump students.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but people aren't giving you a clear answer to your question. The answer is "No". That notation is an abomination.

Comment: OK, to be explicit, I added a point #3 to my answer. @GitGud

Comment: "$2x$" is not a property , so this is no valid definition of a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Most likely, the author meant $A=\{2x\mid x\in\Bbb{N}\},$ but absent-mindedly reverted to their habit of using set-builder notation that
   starts with $$A=\{x\mid \,.$$

   Then, still on autopilot, they recalled that their statement
   ought to feature a multiple of $2$ somewhere, so continued by
   writing $$2x$$ (instead of, say, $\text“x=2k\text”).$

   Finally, remembering that their statement ought to finish off with
   $\:\in\mathbb N,$ they conveniently completed it as $$,x\in\mathbb
   N\}$$ (instead of, say, $\text{“for some }k\in\mathbb N\text”).$
2. Making sense of the [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Examples) (these two sets are equivalent):

   - $$A=\{2k\mid k\in\Bbb{N}\}$$ the set of numbers of the form $2k$ such that $k$ is natural;
   - $$A=\{x\mid \exists k{\in}\Bbb{N}\:\: x=2k\}$$ the set of numbers such that each, for some natural $k,$ equals $2k$.
3. As written, the given string $$A=\{x\mid 2x,\;x\in\Bbb{N}\},$$ is not well-formed /meaningful, due to the middle portion $2x$ being just a term instead of a logical formula.

Answer (score 3):

Arguably, it is fine, but it is somewhat informal and ***very*** confusing.

We will often write something like "Let $m,n,k\in\Bbb N$ ..." as a shorthand of $m\in\Bbb N, n\in\Bbb N, k\in\Bbb N$. We are being informal, since we expect other humans to read what we say, and we expect the context is clear enough to understand that.

So, if I wanted to tell you that not only $2x$ is a natural number, but also $x$ itself is a natural number, I could tell you that $x,2x\in\Bbb N$.

If I had written only that $2x\in\Bbb N$, this would have included rational numbers such as $\frac12$ and $\frac32$, but by requiring that $x\in\Bbb N$ as well, I've avoided that.

Consequently, $\{x\mid 2x,x\in\Bbb N\}$ is just $\Bbb N$. Whether or not that was the intention. So, that is kind of a silly way writing it anyway.

Of course, if we wanted the set of *even* natural numbers, then this no longer works (but we can, arguably, substitute $2x$ by $\frac x2$ in that set-builder definition). Or, we could have written, as you suggest $\{x\mid x=2k, k\in\Bbb N\}$, or $\{x\mid\exists k\in\Bbb N, x=2k\}$, or *much more clearly*, $\{2x\mid x\in\Bbb N\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most natural interpretation is $\{ x \, | \, 2x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } x \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (which of course means that the set is just $\mathbb{N}$ itself). Indeed, usually when we write $s,t \in A$, we mean $s \in A$ and $t \in A$. This is demonstrated in, say, how we write the span of two vectors: $\{ su+tv \, | \, s,t \in \mathbb{R} \}$. So, $2x, x \in \mathbb{N}$ should be interpreted similarly.

However, most people working with math would never write something like this, because it is redundant. This leads me to think that this is some sort of exercise for practicing working with sets and mathematical language. If not, then there is probably a typo, and you should check with whoever wrote it.

Answer (score -6):

The best anyone can guess from that fragment is that it means all of the numbers $\frac12, 1, \frac32, 2, \frac52,...$ where $2x\in\mathbb{N}$.

The notation is ambiguous because of the repeated $x$, but most mathematicians would interpret, for example, $\{(a,b)|2a,b\in\mathbb{N}\}$ as meaning "the set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $2a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$".

For example, [this page](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Applied_Discrete_Structures_(Doerr_and_Levasseur)/01%3A_Set_Theory/1.01%3A_Set_Notation_and_Relations) defines
$$
\mathbb{Q}=\{a/b \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0\}\text{.}
$$

The notation $\{x|\text{condition}\}$ means "the set of $x$ which satisfy the condition". Here $\{\}$ means "the set of", and $\mid$ means "such that", so in words
$\{x|x\in\mathbb{R},x>1\}$ means "the set of $x$ such that $x$ is an element of  the set of real numbers, and $x$ is greater than one".

Whatever the fragment means, it is not possible in the normal understanding of this notation that $\{x|2x\in\mathbb{N}\}$ means "the set of even numbers". That would be $\{x|x/2\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Some people seem to be confusing the condition part of the statement as being able to reach leftwards and change the value of the $x$ part.

Comment: The original notation is $\{x\mid 2x,x\in\Bbb{N}\}$, which is obviously invalid. The OP proposed to change it to $\{x \mid x = 2x', x' \in \mathbb N\}$, while you propose to change it to $\{x \mid 2x\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Both of these are valid interpretations, but they are different, and neither is obviously "better" than the other. If anything, OP's variant looks syntactically closer to the original.

Comment: I take it that you're also of the opinion that $2x\in\mathbb{N}$ implies that $x$ is an even number.

Comment: No, and I don't know how you got that from what I've written.

Comment: For example, would you think that $\{(a,b)|2a,b\in\mathbb{N}\}$ means that $a$ is an even number? That's what your comment seems to be saying.

Comment: No again, and I still don't know how you are (mis)reading my comment. Here it is one more and last time. OP's suggested rewrite was $\,\{x \mid x = 2x′, x′ \in \mathbb N\}\,$, which is the set of even numbers. Your suggested rewrite was $\,\{x \mid 2 x \in \mathbb N\}\,$, which is the set of multiples of $\,\frac{1}{2}\,$. The two sets are very obviously different, and I don't see how you can read that as meaning that $\,2x \in \mathbb N\,$ implies that $x$ is an even number.

Comment: I did not suggest a rewrite nor did I refer to a rewrite by OP. I said that the only meaningful way to interpret that image is that it means that $2x\in N$.